# Saving and fetching data from a file

Tags: c

I am developing a routing protocol on a Linux OS (ubuntu 12.04) in C language. My question is that I need to save the routing table on an external file, so that if the program is closed or the computer is shut down, the program should be able to fetch the routing table from the file when it is restarted.

What would be the easiest solution for it? I would appreciate if you could explain it a little bit. If it would help you to answer, I save the table `struct routing user_list[40]` here below: the smaller index has a higher priority in the table.

```
struct routing {
   int hop_distance;
   char senderID[16]; // 192.168.001.122
   char gateway[16];
};

struct routing user_list[40] = { [0] = {0, {0}, {0}, {0} } };
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not save it to a file that has the same structure as `struct routing`? I. e. a for example 4-byte integer, then a 16-byte string, then another 16-byte string.

Comment: Storing the IP as 16 characters is a weird idea. You're much better off simply storing them as they're represented in the IP protocol packets, that is - as a 32-bit number.

Comment: H2CO3: I am new in C. Could you please tell me what functions do I need to use to save and fetch the data. And what type of file (extension) would you recommend me to use for it?

Comment: Daniel: Right, I did not state that the code above is part of a code, the reason that I am using char array is the convenience, because I need to have IP addresses as char array.

Comment: @sven you don't need anything beyond `read()` and `write()` - but you should google these. Even better, grab a good C tutorial - if you don't have a clue how to write to a file, that's serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man fread

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
...
RETURN VALUE
fread()  and  fwrite() return the number of items successfully read or written (i.e., not the number of charac‐
ters).  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).
```

the easiest solution

```
int nb_written = fwrite(&user_list, sizeof(struct routing), 40, myfile);
int nb_read = fread(&user_list, sizeof(struct routing), 40, myfile);
```

As indicated in the comments:

- the file generated will not be portable due to int type which is dependent of architecture.
- the returned values must be checked to handle io errors

Comment: Note that this easiest solution will result in nonportable files, but that might be alright for the OP's use case.

Comment: Just remember to check the return values from fread/fwrite so that you can handle the error conditions appropriately (i.e. tell the user that the file cannot be written and that data may be lost...)

Comment: Oh, and you will need the corresponding fopen and fclose functions to establish/destroy the file pointer needed in fread/fwrite.

Comment: Using `htonl()` and `ntohl()` the program gets portable. Ex. `hop_distance = ntonl(value); //network byte order`, `value = ntohl(hop_distance); //host byte order`

Comment: I implemented the code by `fread()` and `fwrite()`, the code saves and fetches the routing table, however, it always return the `int hop_distance` value as `0`. Could you please advise how to save and read value of integer (hop_distance)?

Answer (score 1):

See [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [write](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) to save this data. Store the IP addresses as binary (i.e. 4 bytes).